# Too many calls to mprotect

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, system-calls

I am working on a parallel app (C, pthread). I traced the system calls because at some point I have bad parallel performances. My traces shown that my program calls `mprotect()` many many times ... enough to significantly slow down my program.

I do allocate a lot of memory (with `malloc()`) but there is only a reasonable number of calls to `brk()` to increase the heap size. So why so many calls to `mprotect()` ?!

Comment: How about tracking your program with strace if you have it(Linux).

Comment: This is precisely what I did.

Answer (score 3):

Are you creating and destroying lots of threads?

Most pthread implementations will add a "guard page" when allocating a threads stack. It's an access protected memory page used to detect stack overflows. I'd expect at least one call to mprotect each time a thread is created or terminated to (un)protect the guard page. If this is the case, there are several obvious strategies:

1. Set the guard page size to zero using `pthread_attr_setguardsize()` before creating threads.
2. Use a thread-pool (of as many threads as processors say). Once a thread is done with a task, return it to the pool to get a new task rather than terminate and create a new thread.

Another explanation might be that you're on a platform where a thread's stack will be grown if overflow is detected. I don't think this is implemented on Linux with GCC/Glibc as yet, but there have been some proposals along these lines recently. If you use a lot of stack space whilst processing, you might explicitely increase the initial/minimum stack size using `pthread_attr_setstacksize`.

Or it might be something else entirely!

Comment: No I only create a finite number of threads at the beginning, thanks however.

Comment: Hmm... are you using mmap()? I vaguely recall an issue a colleague of mine had where mprotect() was being called many times - once per page - of an mmapped region. I don't know whether we ever got to the bottom of that one.

Might it be possible to post the strace output?

Comment: @Wuggy looks as if it's been 10 years, but do you recall if you ever found the root cause? I have the same issue using mmap()

Answer (score 2):

If you can, run your program under a debug libc and break on mprotect(). Look at the call stack, see what your code is doing that's leading to the mprotect() calls.

Answer (score 2):

glibc library that has ptmalloc2 for its malloc uses mprotect() internally for micromanagement of heap for threads other than main thread (for main thread, sbrk() is used instead.) malloc() firstly allocates large chunk of memory with mmap() for the thread if a heap area seems to have contention, and then it changes the protection bits of unnecessary portion to make it accessible with mprotect(). Later, when it needs to grow the heap, it changes the protection to read/writable with mprotect() again. Those mprotect() calls are for heap growth and shrink in multithreaded applications.

http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-07/Ferguson/Whitepaper/bh-usa-07-ferguson-WP.pdf
explains this in a bit more detailed way.

Answer (score 0):

The 'valgrind' suite has a tool called 'callgrind' that will tell you what is calling what. If you run the application under 'callgrind', you can then view the resulting profile data with 'kcachegrind' (it can analyze profiles made by 'cachegrind' or 'callgrind'). Then just double-click on 'mprotect' in the left pane and it will show you what code is calling it and how many times.